# Make a frame layout visible using a button click

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I'm trying to make a frame layout visible with button click.
Here is my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Extrastxt"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:hint="Message..."
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

if i will visible Extrastxt to visible,it doesnt work.

Java code:

```
Extrastxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Xamarin code:

```
Extrastxt.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGsY4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to visible your framelayout then, you are supposed to make framelayout's instance visible using **`FrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`**.

check the code below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Extrastxt"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:hint="Message..."
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

in Activity:

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
```

And in button clicked just make it visible or invisible, using **setVisibility** method.

Comment: How can set an item to not be influenced by framlayout?Should i change alhpa?

Comment: what do you mean by "alhpa"? If u hide the parent layout all it's child will be hidden.

Comment: I i will put another element like a textview it shows my edittext above textview. How can i avoid this?

Comment: I didn't get you?Please be clear?What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm tryinng to made an animated edittext.Hiding at start and showing up when user will click a button.The problem if that sometimes i need when activity will start to be be not be invisible. if i will set visible elements then it overlays the textview which is down from it

Comment: I think, for not overlapping you can use linear layout or any other layout.

Comment: Please look my image in updated question.Till now textview is overlapping edittext.Also i need to use frame layout for creating animated down for edittext. Like a search bar.

Comment: I just need to disable overlapping in my textview sometimes. Should i need from xml or from code?

Comment: I can't see any update to question.You can have linearlayout in that 1st your framelayout with edittext and 2nd you textview.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you do not properly initialize this View. Bring the question of the initialization code "Extrastxt". 
Also, try to see what happens in the code when the visibility of the object is changed via debug

Comment: Should i make framelayout visible or it doesnt matter?What you mean initialize view?

Comment: i want that You write how You do this:

    EditText Extrastxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Extrastxt);
    Extrastxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

But, i thins, this is no actual right now

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the id to frame layout and set its visbality like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myFrame"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" > <EditText android:id="@+id/Extrastxt" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="200dp" android:hint="Message..." android:visibility="invisible" /> 
</LinearLayout> </FrameLayout>
```

Java code:

```
FrameLayout myFramelyout= (FrameLayout) findViewByID(R.id.myFrame)
```

On click of a button:

`myFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`;